# Как подключить один стиль(scss) на две страницы сразу(Parcel JS)?

Tags: javascript, scss, pug, bundler

У меня есть простейшая структура проекта:

index.pug:

```
doctype html
html(lang="ru")
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    title MyPage
  body
    include src/header/header.pug
```

src/header/header.pug:

```
header
  [some tags]...
  script(src="/src/header/header.js")
```

src/header/header.scss:

```
[some classes]...
```

src/header/header.js:

```
import 'header.scss';
```

Я запускаю бандлер(Parcel JS) | II run the bundler (Parcel JS):

```
parcel *.pug
```

и на localhost:1234 моя страница отображается правильно, пока я не решил добавить ещё одну страницу

about.pug:

```
doctype html
html(lang="ru")
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    title About
  body
    include src/header/header.pug
```

И получилось так, что после сборки бандлером в итоговом файле index.html не обнаружилось стилей(=> тега link), т.е. бандлер подключает стили только в первый попавшийся по алфавиту файл(about.pug) P.S header появляется в обоих файлах(index и about),а вот стили только в about

Я пробовал для каждой точки входа(страницы) создать js файл для импорта туда css классов, но поскольку я хочу чтобы в обеих страницах был один и тот же header, то это приводит к дублированию классов для header и проект становится тяжелее и непроизводительнее Я пытаюсь решить эту проблему уже НЕДЕЛЮ

Заранее спасибо!!!